# Android - How to start the animation of items in a grid view on button Click when using GridLayoutAnimationController?

Tags: android, animation, gridview

I have a custom `GridView` and I want to start the animation of items inside the grid view on click of button. I tried with `GridLayoutAnimationController` but it didn't work. When I set the layout animation using `GridLayoutAnimationController` then only visible items start animating and if I scroll down then items below won't animate. Appreciate any pointers to solve this issue.